# model_main.py file is using Python2.7 instead of Python3

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently using python3 to run model_main.py file. I followed each step to [install object_detection api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md)

I've made sure that each command is run with a python3 prefix but after running the command:

`python3 model_main.py --logtostderr --train_dir=custom1/training --pipeline_config_path=hand_inference_graph/pipeline.config`

I'm getting an error:
`ImportError: /home/abrar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/pycocotools/_mask.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct`

The model_main.py file is using python2.7 every time I run the command.

Comment: To get away from all the headache just create a python3 virtual environment and install your packages inside that. It wouldn't be worth debugging your current situation IMHO

Comment: I tried to run it in a separate python3 env too but it isn't working and it still gets the path from python2.7.

Answer (score 0):

offhand, I'd say that somehow /home/abrar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/pycocotools is being added to your path which, by name, implies a directory full of python2.7 stuff.  Try adding:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

to the top of your script to determine what locations are being searched for modules.  If the pycocotools directory  is being added somehow, you'll need to either remove it from your path or find out where it's being added and stopping it.

Comment: I tried to get a print and it shows: '/home/abrar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research', '/home/abrar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/slim'. Others are getting the same sort of paths but with python3.6.

Comment: after all of the "imports" you need, and after the "import sys", add a line that reads sys.path.remove(<dirname>) for each of the python 2.7 directories in your path.  Also, check for an environment variable PYTHONPATH where those directories may be getting included.  If you're importing stuff that's python2.7 and you're running python3.x you will, in all likelihood, have issues.

Comment: start the program with: import sys, then "for a in sys.path sys.path.remove(a)" then try running it.  That'll remove anything other than standard libraries from you path